# Selenium - Find element using xpath or cssSelector

Tags: java, selenium

I need to click on or find element "Compute vmSwitch". I tried many ways using xpath (class & contains), cssSelector as well, but could not able to locate element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'nopadding vm-create-text-style-3 block-with-text-4  ng-binding') and contains(text(), 'Compute vmSwitch')]")).click();
```

The code is given below:

```
<div class="w-full"><br>
<img class="img-responsive center-block m-t-47" src="/src/icon/background/create_vm_img5.png">
<div class="col-md-12 m-t-md  wordwrap">
<p class="nopadding vm-create-text-style-3 block-with-text-4  ng-binding">
Compute vmSwitch</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u please share html code for which u want to click ?

Comment: <div class="w-full"><br>
            <img class="img-responsive center-block m-t-47" src="/src/icon/background/create_vm_img5.png">
            <div class="col-md-12 m-t-md  wordwrap">
                <p class="nopadding vm-create-text-style-3 block-with-text-4  ng-binding">
                    Compute vmSwitch</p>
            </div>

Comment: Hi Ankur, i want to click on 'Compute vmSwitch', for which i tried all possible ways..

Comment: //*[text()='Compute vmSwitch'] or //p[text()='Compute vmSwitch'] , can u try this

Comment: In ur xpath y u have use span tag . i'm not seeing any span tag in ur code? u can use it this way //p[contains(@class,'nopadding vm-create-text-style-3 block-with-text-4 ng-binding') and contains(text(), ' Compute vmSwitch')]

Answer (score 1):

Why do you try with the span tag?
If this is your html:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div class="w-full">
   <br> 
   <img class="img-responsive center-block m-t-47" src="/src/icon/background/create_vm_img5.png"> 
   <div class="col-md-12 m-t-md wordwrap"> 
    <p class="nopadding vm-create-text-style-3 block-with-text-4 ng-binding"> Compute vmSwitch</p> 
   </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

you could try:

```
    WebElement elem2= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='w-full']"));
    elem2.findElement(By.xpath(".//p[text()=' Compute vmSwitch']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur & Durden for your help. But unfortunately i couldn't able to locate the element by using either ways..

Comment: Can you please share ? ur url